# How to loop many factors into one function

Tags: r

I have a large data frame regarding Covid patients. I have included a very simplified version of what this frame looks like.

```
CovidFake <- data.frame(DateReporting=sample(seq(as.Date("2020-10-1"), as.Date("2020-11-01"), by="day"), 50, replace=TRUE),
                        Industry=sample(c("Minor or Student", "Educational Services", "Medical Services", "Food Production"),50, replace =TRUE))
```

I want use ggplot to make a graph of the daily cases by industry of the patient. I have this function to structure the frame so ggplot can graph it.

```
library(zoo)

MainFunction <- function(MainFrame, CatVal){
  Frame <- subset(MainFrame, Industry==CatVal)
  Frame <- as.data.frame(table(Frame$DateReporting))
  colnames(Frame) <- c("Var1", "Freq")
  Frame$Var1 <- as.Date(Frame$Var1, "%Y-%m-%d")
  Frame <- Frame %>%  complete(Var1 = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                               as.Date("2020-11-01", "%Y-%m-%d"), by="day"))
  Frame$Freq <- replace_na(Frame$Freq, 0)
  Frame$CumSum <- cumsum(Frame$Freq)
  Frame$Cat <- CatVal
  Frame$SevenDayAverage <- rollmean(Frame$Freq, 7, fill=NA, align = "right")
  colnames(Frame) <- c("Date", "DailyCases", "CumSum", "Industry", "SevenDayAve")
  Frame <- subset(Frame, Date >= "2020-03-13")
  return(Frame)
}
```

I need to create a frame that has all of these industries, so I've been doing something like this.

```
IndGraph <- rbind(MainFunction(CovidFake, "Minor or Student"), 
MainFunction(CovidFake, "Educational Services"), 
MainFunction(CovidFake, "Medical Services"), 
MainFunction(CovidFake, "Food Production"))
```

The true frame has about 15 industries, so the code gets pretty long and seemingly unnecessarily repetitive. Is there anyway to loop in all the factors into the function and do this in one? Or is there a simpler way to structure the frame? I'm new to R so any and all help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a for loop:

```
IndGraph <- vector()
for(i in CovidFake$Industry){
  IndGraph <- rbind(IndGraph, MainFunction(CovidFake, i))}
```

Output:

```
> IndGraph
# A tibble: 1,600 x 5
   Date       DailyCases CumSum Industry         SevenDayAve
   <date>          <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 2020-10-01          0      0 Minor or Student      NA    
 2 2020-10-02          0      0 Minor or Student      NA    
 3 2020-10-03          1      1 Minor or Student      NA    
 4 2020-10-04          0      1 Minor or Student      NA    
 5 2020-10-05          0      1 Minor or Student      NA    
 6 2020-10-06          0      1 Minor or Student      NA    
 7 2020-10-07          1      2 Minor or Student       0.286
 8 2020-10-08          1      3 Minor or Student       0.429
 9 2020-10-09          2      5 Minor or Student       0.714
10 2020-10-10          0      5 Minor or Student       0.571
# ... with 1,590 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(unique(CovidFake$Industry), FUN = function(x, y = CovidFake) MainFunction(y, x)))
```